# How to convert the following code to LINQ format?

Tags: .net, performance, linq, c#-4.0, foreach

Code:

```
foreach (var testType in projectData.TestTypes.OrderBy(it => it.TestName))
{
     var testList = new TestList
     {
          benchTestTypeName = testType.TestName,
          DataProvider = this.projectDataService.CurrentDataProvider,
          ProjectData = projectData
     };
     this.tabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = testType.TestName, Content = testList });
}
```

How to convert the above code to `LINQ` format? If we convert to Linq, Is there will be a little improvement in the execution time `(i.e)`, whether the execution time can be little reduced? As of now, it takes around 4 to 5 seconds for `15 TestTypes`.

Comment: LINQ doesn't improve performance. I don't understand why people think this. They are clearly confusing Entity Framework and LINQ in how the execution happens. LINQ is just another way to express statements to happen. So if you are saying it takes 4-5 secs to execute then LINQ is not necessarily going to improve that. This is down to the code itself which needs to be improved. What you maybe referring to is deferred execution.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas LINQ is main stream, so ALL NEED LINQ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
var items = projectData.TestTypes
                       .OrderBy(it => it.TestName)
                       .Select(testType=> new TestList
                       {
                           benchTestTypeName = testType.TestName,
                           DataProvider = this.projectDataService.CurrentDataProvider,
                           ProjectData = projectData
                       });

foreach(var item in items)
   tabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = item.benchTestTypeName, Content = item });
```

Comment: In `Header = item.TestName`, the `TestName` is not populated.

Comment: @JohnStephen You are right. I just corrected it. Thank you !

Comment: Thank You, Now the code execution time reduced by 1 second.